# Keeping this combo box enabled

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I have 3 rad drop down lists. On page load `ComBox_MDCList` is disabled until one of other drop downs selected index = "Pizza". The problem is that after it is enabled by the first dropdown, if the 2nd dropdown is selected and does not = Pizza it will then disable again. How can I keep `ComBox_MDCList` enabled as long as 1 dropdown = Pizza?

Page Load

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ComBox_MDCList.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

sub called

```
 Protected Sub MDCList()
        If (ComBox_Growth1.Text Or ComBox_Growth2.Text = "Pizza") Then
            ComBox_MDCList.Enabled = True
        Else
            ComBox_MDCList.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub
```

1st drop box vb

```
  Protected Sub ComBox_Growth1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs) Handles ComBox_Growth1.SelectedIndexChanged

    If ComBox_Growth1.Text = "Pizza" Then
        MDCList()
    End If

End Sub
```

2nd drop box vb

```
Protected Sub ComBox_Growth2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs) Handles ComBox_Growth2.SelectedIndexChanged

    If ComBox_Growth2.Text = "Pizza" Then
        MDCList()
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Protected Sub MDCList()
     If (ComBox_Growth1.Text = "Pizza" Or ComBox_Growth2.Text = "Pizza") Then
         ComBox_MDCList.Enabled = True
     Else
         ComBox_MDCList.Enabled = False
     End If
End Sub

Protected Sub ComBox_Growth1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs) Handles ComBox_Growth1.SelectedIndexChanged
     MDCList()
End Sub

Protected Sub ComBox_Growth2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs) Handles ComBox_Growth2.SelectedIndexChanged
     MDCList()
End Sub
```